# Unable to pass image to another UIViewController over present modally segue

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode7

I tried to pass an image to another `imageView` of destination `UIView` which is connected to source `UIView` over present Modally segue.

I tried to pass data through segue and as well set image (i.e. NSData - Core Data) in source UIView through Outlet but I got an error [image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8PNc.png) in console -

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

```
  //Code of destination UIView
   import UIKit
   import CoreData
   class ReviewViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var backgroundImageView:UIImageView!
   var subject:Semester!       

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    backgroundImageView?.image = UIImage(data: subject.image!)
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    backgroundImageView.addSubview(blurEffectView)

   // Code of Source UIView
  import UIKit
  import CoreData

  class SubjectDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
  @IBOutlet var facultyImageView:UIImageView!
  var subject:Semester!

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "destinationidentifier"
    {
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ReviewViewController
            destinationController.backgroundImageView?.image = self.facultyImageView.image
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is `backgroundImageView` object is nil because `destinationController` is not currently in `window` hierarchy.

So Change your `prepareForSegue` like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "destinationidentifier"
    {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ReviewViewController
        destinationController.image = self.facultyImageView.image
    }
}
```

Now create one image object in `ReviewViewController` like below and add one line in `viewDidLoad`

```
var image: UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.backgroundImageView?.image = self.image
}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong as you are setting image directly inside outlet without passing value using var or property.

1) Declare variable first

```
var backgroundImage : UIImage!
```

2) Set the value inside that variable while push

```
destinationController.backgroundImage = self.facultyImageView.image
```

Comment: Actually not. Thats why i am tired of this

Comment: Still you are facing issue?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this, Try to send image using UIImage rather then ImageView,

```
//Code of destination UIView
import UIKit
import CoreData
class ReviewViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var backgroundImageView:UIImageView!
var backgroundImage : UIImage!
var subject:Semester!       

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
//backgroundImageView?.image = UIImage(data: subject.image!)
backgroundImageView?.image = self. backgroundImage
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
backgroundImageView.addSubview(blurEffectView)

// Code of Source UIView
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SubjectDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var facultyImageView:UIImageView!
var subject:Semester!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)        {
if segue.identifier == "destinationidentifier"
{
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ReviewViewController
        destinationController.backgroundImage = self.facultyImageView.image
 }
}
```

Hope this will help you.